# Multiple progress bar for multiple video file upload via Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Am stuck with a problem where I need to upload video files from remote server and show the progress of uploading file. If i upload multiple URL's of video file at the same time the view should show multiple progress bar with the uploading progress. I don't know how to do that.

I have a got a code which generates a single progress bar.

my ajax code

```
function remote_up()
    {

        var links = [];
        $.each($('#comment').val().split(/\n/), function (i, line) {
            if (line) {
                links.push(line);
            } else {
                links.push("");
            }
        });
        //alert(links);return false;
        $.ajax({

                 'url'      :  '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+"Test/remote_upload",
                 'type'     : 'POST', //the way you want to send data to your URL
                 'data'     : {'links' : links},
                 'xhr'      : function ()
                                {
                                    var jqXHR = null;
                                    if ( window.ActiveXObject )
                                    {
                                        jqXHR = new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        jqXHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                                    }
                                    //Upload progress
                                    jqXHR.upload.addEventListener( "progress", function ( evt )
                                    {
                                        if ( evt.lengthComputable )
                                        {
                                            var percentComplete = Math.round( (evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total );
                                             $('#progress').css('background-color', 'green')
                                                            .css('width', +percentComplete+'%');
                                             $("#progress").html(percentComplete + '%');
                                            // $("#progress").width(percentComplete);
                                            //Do something with upload progress     
                                            console.log( 'Uploaded percent', percentComplete );
                                        }
                                    }, false );

                                    return jqXHR;
                                },
                 'success'  : function(data){ //probably this request will return anything, it'll be put in var "data"

                                if(data == 0)
                                {
                                    $.blockUI({ 
                                              message: 'Uploading File.....',
                                              css: { 
                                                border: 'none', 
                                                padding: '15px', 
                                                backgroundColor: '#000', 
                                                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                                                '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                                                opacity: '.5', 
                                                color: '#fff',
                                                fontSize: '18px',
                                                fontFamily: 'Verdana,Arial',
                                                fontWeight: 200,
                                            } }); 

                                    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
                                    $('.help-block-error').html('Successfully Uploaded');
                                    $('p .help-block-error').fadeIn(3000);
                                     $("#progress").hide();

                                }

                                $('#comment').val('');
                                 console.log( 'Completed.' );

                        }
                 });

    }
    /*EOF function remote upload*/
```

My html view

```
<div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="links" class="form-control" rows="7" id="comment" placeholder="Insert your links (1line = 1 link)"></textarea>
                                        </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 text-right"><button type="submit" onclick="remote_up();" class="submit-2">Submit</button></div>

<div class="w3-light-grey w3-tiny">
                                <div class="w3-container w3-green" id="progress" ></div>
                            </div>
```

For uploading the video files i use copy command in my controller function.

controller function

```
function test()
{
      $remote_url   =   $_POST['links'];
        //$filesizes    =   array();
        foreach($remote_url as $r_url)
        {
            $url        =   $r_url;
            $file1      =   basename($url);
            $file_name  =   getFileName($file1);
            $path       =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pandaload/testuploads/';
            if(!copy($url,$path.'/'.$file_name)) {
                // die('Failed to copy file');
                echo "Failed to copy file";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "File Uploaded";
            }
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'd have to do each one in a separate ajax request, I think. Bear in mind your progress bar only monitors the progress of your ajax request. It has no way of knowing what the server is actually doing while the request is being processed.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. Can you explain?

Comment: What I meant was the progress bar you've got above is monitoring the ajax request you're making to _your_ PHP server. That's only 1 request. It cannot distinguish which part of the process is the upload of file A, and which part is the upload for file B, in order to make separate progress bars. It's all one big ajax request. So to get separate progress bars, you would need separate ajax requests, once for each file being uploaded.